# Compression image without very high quality image in c#

Tags: c#, image, compression

I do not need a very high quality image. I will sent this image with socket so I need this image small as possible I need a method to compression image

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog Open_File = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (Open_File.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Open_File.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int length = (int)fileStream.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            Image x = byteArrayToImage(buffer);//this image I want to compression
            //.............................
        }
    }

    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

Comment: [Google => c# image compression](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+image+compression&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS495US495&sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS495US495&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23+image+compression&oq=c%23+image+compression&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i8i30l2.24699.24699.1.24824.1.1.0.0.0.0.58.58.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.cHqHcZxFZWQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1375b075ee4b71b2&biw=1745&bih=860)?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: [Compression image in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024708/compression-image-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Brad Rem (Compression image in C#) I asked this question and there is no answer so I asked the same question with another formula

Comment: @SimpleCoder The first thing I thought to get answer put **c# image compression** in Google

Answer (score 1):

Motaz,

I worked on an image processing project some while back. The project required the Compression/Decompression of the images. You have two options to do what you want:
1) You can write the algorithm yourself.

2) You can use a library for the Compression/Decompression of the images.
If you want to use a library, you also have to options:
A- You can use open source libraries and articles available on the internet such as the following:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4769/In-Memory-Image-Compression 
Or you can use a library such as Aforge

B- You can use commercial library such as leadtools sdk that allows you to increase the compression by just changing the quality factor. Also, for their j2k  format you can set the size you want the image to have. For a code sample: see the following links:
For quality factor:
www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.codecspngoptions.html#Example_CS
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.codecsjpegoptions.html#Example_CS
For the setting the J2K file size:
www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/co/leadtools.codecs~leadtools.codecs.codecsjpeg2000options.html#Example_CS
Using the TargetFileSize property you can set the file size.

In my cause, we decided to go with the commercial toolkit because it gave us more features, better quality and better performance.